# deployment error - django to elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image: log]I am trying to deploy a django app to AWS using elastic beanstalk but it is saying that my requirements.txt is invalid when I run eb deploy. Can someone please help?

Do I need to create eb virtual environment inside conda virtual env ? Or i can use any one ? Is it the same thing ?

Error : [image: log]

requirements.txt

```
alabaster==0.7.10
anaconda-client==1.6.9
anaconda-navigator==1.7.0
anaconda-project==0.8.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==1.6.1
astropy==2.0.3
attrs==17.4.0
Babel==2.5.3
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
bitarray==0.8.1
bkcharts==0.2
blaze==0.11.3
bleach==2.1.2
bokeh==0.12.13
boto==2.48.0
botocore==1.10.11
Bottleneck==1.2.1
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.4
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
cloudpickle==0.5.2
clyent==1.2.2
colorama==0.3.7
comtypes==1.1.4
conda==4.5.2
conda-build==3.4.1
conda-verify==2.0.0
contextlib2==0.5.5
cryptography==2.1.4
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.27.3
cytoolz==0.9.0
dask==0.16.1
datashape==0.5.4
decorator==4.2.1
distributed==1.20.2
Django==2.0.4
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-bootstrap3==10.0.1
django-bootstrap4==0.0.6
django-braces==1.13.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-environ==0.4.4
django-forms-bootstrap==3.1.0
django-multiselectfield==0.1.8
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-select2==6.0.2
djangorestframework==3.8.2
docutils==0.14
entrypoints==0.2.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.0.2
filelock==2.0.13
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.3
gevent==1.2.2
glob2==0.6
greenlet==0.4.12
h5py==2.7.1
heapdict==1.0.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.6
imageio==2.2.0
imagesize==0.7.1
ipython==6.2.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.1.1
isort==4.2.15
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.3
jedi==0.11.1
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.3
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.2
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
jupyterlab==0.31.4
jupyterlab-launcher==0.10.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1 
llvmlite==0.21.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml==4.1.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==2.1.2
mccabe==0.6.1
menuinst==1.4.11
mistune==0.8.3
mpmath==1.0.0
msgpack-python==0.5.1
multipledispatch==0.4.9
navigator-updater==0.1.0
nbconvert==5.3.1
nbformat==4.4.0
networkx==2.1
nltk==3.2.5
nose==1.3.7
notebook==5.4.0
numba==0.36.2
numexpr==2.6.4
numpy==1.14.0
numpydoc==0.7.0
odo==0.5.1
olefile==0.45.1
openpyxl==2.4.10
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.22.0
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.1.1
partd==0.3.8
path.py==10.5
pathlib2==2.3.0
patsy==0.5.0
pep8==1.7.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==5.1.0
pkginfo==1.4.1
pluggy==0.6.0
ply==3.10
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
psutil==5.4.3
py==1.5.2
pyasn1==0.4.2
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser==2.18
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0.1
pyflakes==1.6.0
Pygments==2.2.0
pylint==1.8.2
pyodbc==4.0.22
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
PySocks==1.6.7
pytest==3.3.2
python-dateutil==2.7.2
pytz==2018.4
PyWavelets==0.5.2
pywin32==222
pywinpty==0.5
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==16.0.3
QtAwesome==0.4.4
qtconsole==4.3.1
QtPy==1.3.1
requests==2.18.4
rope==0.10.7
rsa==3.4.2
ruamel-yaml==0.15.35
s3transfer==0.1.13
scikit-image==0.13.1
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==1.0.0
seaborn==0.8.1
Send2Trash==1.4.2
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.11.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
sortedcollections==0.5.3
sortedcontainers==1.5.9
south==1.0.2
Sphinx==1.6.6
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.0.1
spyder==3.2.6
SQLAlchemy==1.2.1
statsmodels==0.8.0
sympy==1.1.1
tables==3.4.2
tblib==1.3.2
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.3.1
toolz==0.9.0
tornado==4.5.3
traitlets==4.3.2
typing==3.6.2
unicodecsv==0.14.1
urllib3==1.22
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
widgetsnbextension==3.1.0
win-inet-pton==1.0.1
win-unicode-console==0.5
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.10.11
xlrd==1.1.0
XlsxWriter==1.0.2
xlwings==0.11.5
xlwt==1.3.0
zict==0.1.3
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Can you provide the exact error message? Can you provide your requirements.txt?

Comment: The error message seems to suggest you might find more information in the environment's log files. I suspect it may be complaining about `backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0`?

Comment: i think I have issues with Anaconda. Can someone please suggest me how to correct it ?

Comment: @user, can you check the output of `eb logs`? There should be an indication in the `/var/log/eb-activity.log` section as to what the problem really is.

Comment: i have included the logs. Can you please help ?